# htop does not show a process

Tags: process, ps, top, cifs, htop

When using `top`, it shows me that `cifsd` has used lots of CPU time but in `htop` the process does not show up at all. I have tried enabling threads (with `H`) in htop, to no avail. It also does not show up in `pstree`, even when using parameters that might show me more info (`-apcls`).

I can find its process id in `/proc` so it exists.

In `ps aux` it shows up but in square brackets: `[cifsd]` is the value of the last column (titled `COMMAND`).

What kind of a process is this? From the CPU time over uptime, it seems to use 7.8% CPU on average (and it's pretty constant, when looking at `top`), so it's definitely a process of interest, but htop hides it.

Comment: Is it a kernel module? I suspect it must be something around that...

Comment: Looks like a kernel thread, which is by default hidden in htop. So, update your configuration F2 -> Display Options -> Remove "x" at "Hide kernel threads".

Comment: @Thomas Ah, I did not know what square brackets indicated nor that htop hides those by default. Thanks! You should have posted as answer by the way, being earlier than ctx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to setup and change your 'Display' options:

```
F2 > Display options
```

Do not hide kernel threads and show custom thread names:

```
[ ] Hide kernel threads
[x] Show custom thread names
```

Save:

```
F10
```